# How to develop https site with Spring 3.x?

Tags: security, spring, https

I am a newbie in Spring based web development.

Our site is Spring based and is currently http based (so quite insecure).
Since, the site is not live yet, we are sending login/password also through a normal JSON request to server and have focussed mostly on JSP, UI design, SQL queries etc.

Now, we want to shift to focus on security and shift to https as a first step.

I have read a no. of web-pages and some spring books but none seems to provide a clear answer on how Spring can be used to provide https security.
Can some one please help me in achieving the above?

Please let me know if my question is not clear. I will try to add more details ASAP.

Our web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd    
"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--> Mapping for serving static web-content <-->
<!--> The resources folder must be in parallel to WEB-INF <-->
<!--> The mvc:resources gives "not bound" exception unless bound to a namespace as above for xmlns:mvc <-->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />

</web-app>
```

There is only one controller right now for which, spring-servlet.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="console.controllerpkg" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. If you can recommend me a good example based site/book on spring, it would be much appreciated. Most of the sites/books I have seen lay much emphasis on theory but very little examples. That has left me a little confused.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Dave says, you need to configure your container to serve SSL, and then deploy your spring app into that container. Learn about configuring [Tomcat for SSL.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Alternately, and more flexibly you can [front your container using Apache](http://linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/c875.html), and [enable SSL there.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links nont. I will go through them tomorrow since its late night for me. Just to re-confirm of what has been answered till now, I have understood that:
1) Spring has nothing to do with SSL.
2) SSL is to be enabled in Tomcat.
Please confirm these two points.

Thanks a lot again for your answers guys.
I would have continued digging Spring if you guys had not helped me.

Comment: Correct, spring doesn't directly handle HTTP or HTTPS. It is deployed into a container like tomcat or jboss, and that container is what deals with SSL or regular HTTP. Those requests are then passed on to Spring to handle. So, yes, if you want to enable SSL, you should do it in your tomcat. BTW, please upvote and/or mark this answer as correct if it was helpful. That's a big reason people like to answer questions here!

Comment: The link in the answer is for Tomcat 5.5, this is the link for Tomcat 7: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Answer (score 4):

Spring is not 100% responsible for configuring SSL.  For that you need to configure the container (jetty, tomcat, etc) to handle SSL.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help guys.
I will re-iterate what I did just for my own record purposes.

First of all, the link provided by nont about 'Tomcat for SSL' was really helpful.
I read all about SSL and Tomcat there and this is what I did:

On the command prompt, enter:
*keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA*
The above command asked me some simple questions needed for a Certificate. I used the password 'changeit' wherever asked (as that is the default password).

On finishing with the above command, it generated a keystore file in C:/Documents and  Settings//.keystore
I copied this .keystore file to tomcat/conf/myKeyStore.jks

Then I added the following to conf/server.xml :

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" 
   maxSpareThreads="75"
   enableLookups="true" 
   disableUploadTimeout="true"
   acceptCount="100" 
   maxThreads="200" debug="5"
   scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
   keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/myKeyStore.jks"
   keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="changeit"
   truststoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/cacerts"
   truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="changeit"
   SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" 
   sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

And that's it!!
Next time, I ran tomcat my old http link did not work.
Then I tried adding sweet 's' to http with a port number of 8443 and lo! everything was up and running again.

Thanks nont for the wonderful link!!

Comment: Just one last thing, after enabling SSL for my webserver, can I be sure that security for my site is complete? Or I need to do something else too? For example, I make a lot of AJAX calls to get data for all my pages. And the sever returns JSON responses to each ajax call. Is that ok? Similarly during login too, an AJAX post request is made having username and password in JSON format. Is that safe?

Comment: anything going through your ssl enabled tomcat will be encrypted if the url starts with "https". it doesnt matter if its ajax or not. it sounds like maybe you generated your own certificate? if so, you might want to buy a "real" cert when you go to production. not that it will be any more secure, only because your users browsers will warn them against websites using self signed certs.

Answer (score 0):

Configure two different web sites, one for http and one for https, the one for http will have just a redirect to the https site.