# Current architecture recommendation for a connected desktop application (in Java)

Tags: java, web-services, web, architecture, desktop-application

I am looking to develop a desktop application which functions as a tool for a purpose to my users. I wish this application to connect to my web server to authenticate a user, and so the user could save the project / data / work on the server.

I would have a site for it with a database (and Spring MVC, Hibernate, etc...), and I was thinking of using HTTP data communication, such as browsers do. User authentication would be done as a POST, and the data could be sent and returned in JSON. I will develop the program with Java, and I'm considering using the [Http Components](https://hc.apache.org/) library, from Apache.

Using NIO, or Sockets libraries might not be good for me (I don't know), because I would have another kind of complexity to work on the server, and frankly I do not know how I would do it. I would have to leave perhaps two server programs running... I do not know how I would do it on the same machine / server. Anyway...

I want to know what is the current (September, 2015) and recommended options for achieving this (with Java), and I will consider an answer as correct if it contains current and real alternatives (no mater how many) that are functional, and with a proper bibliography.

**NOTE**: The use of HTTP was only one option mentioned by me. If there is something better, or more recommended, or optional, please...

**Some things to consider:**

- Safe data transmission (user authentication data).
- Transmission of (possible) megabytes of data.
- Scalability.

### EDIT

I'm editing my question to clarify a few things. Again, we suffer from the use of the internet, where we do not see the tone in a speech or text, and the author's face. I did not want to be rude, arrogant, or mean. I apologize right now if anyone felt offended by it. Other than that, my native language is not English. I use a translator (google) and the little knowledge I have to be able to communicate with people, trying to be as clear, simple and direct as possible, because I know that everyone here has their lives and their occupations. I feel I have to mention this because in my omission, I would be in agreement with what was said to me. I came here on a mission of peace, and information, as well as all my other colleagues in this community.

Regarding my question, I believe there is some misunderstanding as to it being too vague / broad, or based on opinions. I remind you that there is no single way to effect a due action, much less one way to be the best among others, even in the field of exact sciences. How often we do not see more than one acceptable answer here in this community? How often we did not see correct answers considered by users to be barred by other responses with a greater number of votes? And yet, only for an answer have fewer votes than another does not necessarily mean that it is disposable. We still gain with content on it. If it was not the way we are used to here, a question would have only a single correct answer, where only one answer would be given.

I presented a real situation, plausible, which I'm going through (and I believe many other users also pass through it). I was careful/criterioso (not arrogant), of course, because facts were presented. I do not have unlimited resources in my budget to effect any kind of solutions. It is quite possible that some solutions are best for my case than others. Each case is different.

Comment: Both too broad and opinion based (and a bit arrogant).

Comment: Hi @Kayaman. Could you please read my change in my question? Thank you.

Comment: The question still suffers from being both too broad and opinion based. There's no single correct answer, and it's not suitable for the Stackoverflow Q/A format to go through all the current technologies. Questions get closed all the time, even if they may not be completely worthless. It's also often hard or impossible to say what is "better", and it will even depend on your skills. Stackoverflow is not a single stop place for any and all advice, it's expected that developers do their own research as well.

Comment: If you think about it, the system itself is flawed. There should be no correct answer chosen by vote. Just because users vote on answers causes the system to be based on opinions. It would be ideal if answers were given and voted on by relevance, not because they are right or wrong. I believe that a "correct" answer here would have one or more ways to accomplish what I want, as with many questions and many others in the community. Unfortunately, I believe this is not the place for this kind of discussion. Right and wrong, this is very subjective.

Comment: The "correct" answer is chosen by the asker (hopefully) on the basis that it best helped to solve his problem. Often there are non-correct answers that are voted higher than the chosen correct answer due to many reasons (it's actually a better answer but the asker doesn't understand it, it's a matter of opinion, or other reasons). It's not perfect, but it works decently in addition to moderator and hi-score user powers. Your question isn't inherently bad, it's just not a good fit for SO. Google will give you plenty of material, you just need to do some of your own research as well.

Comment: Hi @Kayaman. Just to be clear: this is the second time you deduce that I have not started a research before putting my question here. Ideas like HTTP communication, the use of JSON as data type, and Sockets came from a research made earlier by me. I do not know if you are considering or if you are thinking this, or who read what you said may think the same, but I'm not ... you know ... lazy. As I said, I came here looking for information, just like everyone else. Sorry again for (I do not know anymore), and thank you for your attention.

Comment: No I did see that you've written some thoughts there. This question would've been closed already if it consisted of only the first paragraph. Since you already have an idea that you've described, why not go with it? You could've written the server part already, instead of waiting for someone to give you the "best" choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring MVC and Hibernate. You have to configure container or application server to work over https if you want safe data transmission.

You can find a lot of examples by google search.
[how to develop https site with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811128/how-to-develop-https-site-with-spring-3-x)

Comment: Hi @pavel.konoplianik. I actually already have a website up and running which uses Spring MVC and Hibernate. I only mention this to show my case. I'm looking for a way to create a desktop program that is able to communicate with a server (which could be this one that I'm using). This program should send and receive information securely.